# Java Socket - client not receiving from server

Tags: java

When I run the program it doesn't receive the message from the server. It blocks in the line `o = in.readObject();`. I use (in the class thread) the input Stream created in the class Worker.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("run do worker começou.");
    try {
        //out = w.out;
        //out.flush();
        in = w.in;
        String message = null;
        Object o = null;
        boolean identifier;
        ArrayList<News> receivedNews;
        System.out.println("vai começar while true do worker.");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("object: "+o);
            System.out.println("worker dentro do while.");
            o = in.readObject();
            System.out.println("object 2.0: "+o);
            System.out.println("worker recebeu: "+o.toString());
            if(o instanceof Boolean) {
                identifier = (Boolean) o;
                if(identifier == false) {
                    toWorker = true;
                    System.out.println("recebi o boolean");
                }
            }
            if(o instanceof String && toWorker == true) { //recebe a palavra e guarda-a como atributo
                message = (String) o;
                word = message;
                System.out.println("Worker received word: "+message);
                toWorker = false;
            }
            if(o instanceof ArrayList && toWorker == true) { //recebe as notícias
                receivedNews = (ArrayList<News>) o;
                news = receivedNews;
                System.out.println("Worker received the news");
                newsFinal = searchNews();
                w.sendListToServer(newsFinal);
                toWorker = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The server code :

```
out.writeObject(false); // false = enviar para worker
                out.writeObject(word);
                out.writeObject(news);
```

Comment: It can happen if a socket port is already in use.for an example: you send the data and another application receives it on the same PC

Comment: Try [`flush()`ing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#flush()) the server's output stream.

Comment: @Dezigo I have a class Client and a class Worker, and both should send and receive messages to and from the server. I use the same socket (with the same port number). Should I do it in a different way?

Comment: The same port can be blocked by IDE when you run two applications on the same port. I would do a test. Try to run a server app as a separate java application (like a .jar) not from the IDE, after that run a client.

Comment: @Dezigo I'm already running the server, the client and the worker as a separated java application.

Comment: not enough code, It's hard to tell where a problem is